Why is python calculation with float numbers faster than calculation with integer numbers
This example shows that python calcuation with float numbers is faster than with integer numbers. I am wondering why calculation with integer is not faster than with float
import time
# Number of operations
N = 10**7

# Integer addition
start_time = time.time()
int_result = 0
for i in range(N):
    int_result += 1
int_time = time.time() - start_time

# Float addition
start_time = time.time()
float_result = 0.0
for i in range(N):
    float_result += 1.0
float_time = time.time() - start_time

print(f"Time taken for integer addition: {int_time:.6f} seconds")
print(f"Time taken for float addition: {float_time:.6f} seconds")


Because fixed-length floating point arithmetic is more efficient than arbitrary-length integer arithmetic.

All modern CPUs have hardware floating point, there's no hardware for multi-precision arithmetic.

The trade-off that you make is that you lose precision.

The standard way to run Python code is using the (slow) CPython interpreter. There are faster implementation like PyPy (JIT compiler). Results might be pretty different with PyPy which can operate on native integers thanks to JIT guards. Note that >99% of the time should be spent in CPython overheads here. You should really not do such computation in Python if you care about performance. Using Cython with type annotation can make this multiple order of magnitude faster.

In fact, compilers (like Cython) can completely optimize out your loop and perform int_result=N. They can even see that int_result is not read/useful so they not even assign it. This makes them infinitely faster here ;) ! If we consider the time to measure the timings, I guess we get a >1000000 times faster code.

It'd help to post the results you're getting, for completeness.

Python uses integers with no fixed size. Under the hood it's an array of digits (not base-10 digits, but fixed size integers that fit into 1 array element, to which we refer as "digit" in this case) that can be extended if needed. That's why you can have absurdly large integers in Python.
CPUs have instructions to perform floating point operations and integer operations, but they usually only work with numbers that are 1 machine word long or less. Python integers do not satisfy this condition, but floats do.
Without diving too much into long number arithmetic, integers operations in Python are computed digit by digit. The longer the integers are, the longer the computation takes.
In your code however, the ints do not use more than 1 digit. Still, these are arrays, that require some overhead to be processed.

float is a thin wrapper around whatever floating-point type your hardware provides. int is not; it's an arbitrary-precision type based on arrays of large "digits". A "small" integer is still a single-element array of machine words, rather than a single machine word itself. Operations on such values are necessarily slower than a single machine-integer operation would be.

Even just testing the operands to see if they're small enough for a single-instruction optimization would take time.  I don't know if Python bothers.

It looks like there is a short path for "compact values", but like you say, there is the cost of detecting if the short path is appropriate, which float_add doesn't need.

Now that I think about it, they probably already had the code for compact values from back when Python had two different types of integers.
